# RegExp match word with parenthesis?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have problem with regular expressions. I have strings like this:

```
test(r), testtest(r,r), example, example2, exmp (r,5)
```

I would like to find all words without blanks between text and the parenthesis. From the string above, I want to get:

```
test(r), testtest(r,r)
```

I created this regexp but it catches only brackets with content inside:

```
/\(([^\)]+)\)/g
```

Thanks for all answers.

Edit:
I am working in Ruby, and this regex works perfectly `/\w+\(([^)]+)\)/g`.

What should I do if I would like to separate words with commas between brackets and without? For example how do I get this?

```
testtest(r,r) <-with comma
test(r) <-without comma
```

Comment: Can you tag in which language/application you are using this regex? Also, you do not need to escape `(` or `)` inside of `[ ]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `\w+` in front of the pattern:

```
/\w+\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

This will match one or more 'word' characters (which includes letters, digits, and underscores) followed by an `(`, followed by one or more of any character other than `)`, followed by a `)`.

If you want to know want to be able to capture the word that appears before the parentheses separately, you can put it in a group like this:

```
/(\w+)\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

In your example, this would give group 1: `test` and group 2: `r` for the first match and  group 1: `testtest` and group 2: `r,r` for the second match.

Comment: I think OP wants the `\w+` result to be part of what's captured.

Comment: @ajp15243 It will be captured, it just won't be in the same group. Still, I've provided a bit more information in case OP needs that word separately.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Fair enough, also seems to be what OP needed.

Answer (score 1):

Recently had the same issue myself. Doing this solved my problem:

```
(\w+\([\w, ]+\))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
/\w+\(\w([,]\w)?\)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '''test(r), testtest(r,r), example, example2, exmp (r,5)'''
pattern = r'\w+\([^()]+\)'
m = re.compile(pattern)
results = m.finditer(text)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is 8.5 years old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code.